# mscharts set Xaxis maximum results in Red Cross

Tags: c#, mschart

I have a setup with multiple series in a MScharts Control.
With this method I want to switch between them. 
The first time, this method is called, everything is fine and the series displays correctly.
The second time, and everytime after, the method call causes a Red cross drawn in the control. No Exception is thrown.

```
    private void EnableChart(Series series)
    {
        if (series != null)
        {
            chart1.Series.Clear();
            chart1.Series.Add(series);
            double maxval = series.Points.FindMaxByValue("X").XValue;
            chart1.DataSource = series;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = series.Name;
            chart1.DataBind();
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = maxval; //if commented out = ok
        }
    }
```

If i comment out the last line, the chart shows up but with the X axis values of the old Series, so i cannot see any data.

**Edit: Solved.**

If I use the

```
 chart1.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();
```

instead of

```
 chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = maxval;
```

everything works.

Comment: you can answer your own question and mark it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes `RecalculateAxesScale()` solve your problem because this line :

```
chart1.DataBind();
```

bind data to your Graph and if you add a point after binding you have to recalculate axes :

```
chart1.ChartAreas[0].RecalculateAxesScale();
```

so a better way to solve that :

```
    private void EnableChart(Series series)
    {
        if (series != null)
        {
            chart1.Series.Clear();
            chart1.Series.Add(series);
            double maxval = series.Points.FindMaxByValue("X").XValue;
            chart1.DataSource = series;
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Title = series.Name;

            //switch latest lines and you haven't to recalculate axes
            chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = maxval;
            chart1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```